# Umbraco - Media Picker in Modal Popup for Custom section

Tags: umbraco

I have this piece of code which opens a Model Window with a content picker and returns a breadrumb string for any selected node. This works in a custom area.

What I want to do is, also in a custom area, have a **media picker** open in a modal popup so I can get the id of the media item selected. I was hoping just to adapt this code ('content'-->'media' as a start) but my changes haven't worked and also I don't know if its meant to work. The 'GetPickerurl' is depretiated but I don't know if there is a new way? I'm using umbraco 6.1.6. Many Thanks

```
<script>
function showTree() {
    var treePicker = parent.UmbClientMgr.openModalWindow('@(umbraco.uicontrols.TreeUrlGenerator.GetPickerUrl(true,"content","content"))', 'Select', true, 600, 425, null, null, null, function (args) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/umbraco/webservices/legacyAjaxCalls.asmx/GetNodeBreadcrumbs',
            data: '{ "nodeId": ' + args.outVal + ' }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                var a = msg.d;
                var name = a[a.length - 1];
                var breadcrumbs = a.join(" > ");

                $('p#pickedContent').html(breadcrumbs);
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
<a href="javascript: showTree();">Pick Content</a>
<p id="pickedContent"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found. After looking at the urls in the popup I could see that the string wasn't being encoded properly-

```
/dialogs/treepicker.aspx?rnd=b235c90e995344f6a2e299a21013c7a8&amp;id=-1&amp;treeType=media&amp;contextMenu=true&amp;isDialog=false&amp
```

It just needed Html.Raw around the call - also note the "media" parameters.

```
parent.UmbClientMgr.openModalWindow('@(Html.Raw(umbraco.uicontrols.TreeUrlGenerator.GetPickerUrl("media", "media")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your approach before, but you can use the build in media and content picker control.
Include this in your head of the aspx file

```
<%@ Register Namespace="umbraco.uicontrols.TreePicker" Assembly="controls" TagPrefix="umbtree"  %>
```

To get a Media picker control

```
<umbtree:SimpleMediaPicker runat="server" id="MediaSimpleContentPicker" />
```

and content picker

```
<umbtree:SimpleContentPicker runat="server" id="TreeSimpleContentPicker" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this - The approach was taken from something similar in the Umbraco source